# Depth map is flat in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to get depth map in Three.js. I use MeshDepthMaterial.

```
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial() );
```

Although I use logarithmic depth buffer

```
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true, logarithmicDepthBuffer: true  } );
```

I still get depth maps without having any variations. I think scale is too little to see the variations. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE3Jb.jpg

Any idea about how to get a nice depth map?

Comment: Probably you need to specidy `near` and `far` properties of THREE.Camera which you are rendering with.

Comment: you are too far. move closer.

Comment: Okay thanks for the comments. I was setting near far, but there was still no change. What I have recognized, after setting near and far, projection matrix should be updated as the `following:frameCamera.updateProjectionMatrix ()`